# Latin expression/abbreviation meaning "similar to"

Tags: abbreviations

I recall seeing an expression with this same meaning in a linguistics paper.

For instance:

> This adjective declines like an e-stem noun.
>
> (1)- [The abbreviation I am looking for] e-stem.

This will be useful to write a footnote laconically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't think of one. cf. (Lat. *confer* or compare) is occasionally used to contrast one source and another, but you're neither contrasting nor citing a source.

Comment: Could it be ‘cf’, which is short for Latin ‘confer’ (cited by TaliesMerlin). In works of scholarship it occurs in footnotes, recommending a reference with which the point being made could be compared (imperative ‘confer’ = ‘compare’.), usually for similarities.

Comment: I've never seen *sicut* used for this, but neither would it surprise me to do so.

Comment: I know there's one that's much closer to "similar to" than "cf." and I will be patiently following responses to this question until it turns up.